# CSS positioning?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I was hoping someone might be able to assist me with a simple CSS positioning question.
I have a link I want to show next to my top navigation but I do not want it to move in different browser sizes.

I have create a div with a class called "language" as seen below.

```
        <!-- nav -->
            <nav id="nav-main" role="navigation"> 
                <?php alanbrandt_nav(); ?>
            </nav>
            <div class="language">
                <a href="http://alanbrandt.dk" target="_blank">Dansk</a>
            </div>
```

I have also created the following CSS class but when I use this all the article links in the menu can't be clicked. It's as if the link has been removed from the menu items.

```
.language {
  position:relative;
  left:340px;
  top:-27px;

}
```

Ideally the link should appear aligned to the right hand edge of the image but horizontally aligned with the top navigation bar. The above achieves the correct layout but stops the navigation from working as none of the menu items are active.

http://alanbrandt.com

Can someone tell me how I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: can you paste your code in JsFiddle. we'll be able to help you much better

Comment: In CSS to target a class, you need to add a dot in front of the classname, like this: `.language`. When targeting an id, you use `#id_name`.

Comment: Btw, why not add this link to your nav?

Comment: You should avoid pixel-based positioning like that if there is no real need. In this case you want the nav and language link to render inline, so do just that: `#nav-main { display: inline-block }` and use a `<span>` for the language link. That will get you 90% of the way.

Comment: The reason I haven't added it to the navigation block is because I wasn't sure how to stop it from moving when I clicked on the search flyout icon.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your language div into the `nav`, and use absolute positioning :

**HTML**

```
<!-- nav -->
<nav id="nav-main" role="navigation"> 
    <?php alanbrandt_nav(); ?>
    <div class="language">
        <a href="http://alanbrandt.dk" target="_blank">Dansk</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav-main {
    position: relative;
    width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#nav-main .language {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: you can't set the width of `nav` website is responsive and i think if you apply width to `nav` then you have to handle it on `media queries`

Comment: Then we can set `nav` width only for desktop use. It seems media queries are already in use, so fall back to `width: 100%` for tablets/phones should be enought.

Comment: Ya, meanwhile, you already changed your code. Set `#nav-main .language { width: auto; }` to see this code working.

Comment: I can't get this to work as you have suggested above... It shows up just the same as if I added the `div` tags outside the `nav` tag... Thanks for the effort anyway...

Answer (score 0):

you need a dot before the class name:

```
.language {
  position:relative;
  left:200px;
  top:40px;
}
```